# Failed to compile vue application

Tags: webpack, vue.js, sass, frontend, bulma

I am starting to study Vue.js and I'm trying to make SPA. I want to use bulma. And I know that I need SASS for this. I run next command in my terminal:

```
npm install node-sass sass-loader style-loader --save-dev
```

after this I have restarted local dev server by using

```
npm run dev
```

Finally, as result I have the following:

[image]

In component I used following code:

```
<style lang="sass">
    @import "../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass"

    #app
        font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
         text-align: center
         color: #2c3e50
         margin-top: 60px
</style>
```

I even try to fix my webpack.base.conf.js: 
I have added next code to this file:
[image]

I don't know is it correct or not. Guys, tell me please where is mistake?

Comment: You might consider using https://buefy.github.io/#/

Comment: No no! Thank you, but I don't familiar with clear Bulma. And I would like to understand, how I can use it firstle, after this I will try some extentions.